# Reading images that Firefox can read but GraphicsMagick cannot?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

Users can upload images to my page. The problem is that when I try to convert them I get these errors:
gm convert: Improper image header
gm convert: Memory allocation failed

I can see them in Firefox/Safari/Chrome without a problem. Is there a way to "fix" these images command line. Some other utility to read and save them into a correct(non corrupt) format? Or maybe let graphicsmagick ignore these errors?

Comment: How about posting a couple so we can maybe work out what the problem is?

Comment: You cannot let gm ignore the error; you'll get no output image.  I don't have a clue about how to fix the images, without further information about them.